# JS - Set multidimensional array from AJAX output

Tags: javascript, jquery, split

Let's say I receive some data from jQuery Ajax output.

```
var tags = call_ajax('order/get_data', 'user_id=' + $('#user_id').val());
```

Outputted string from **PHP** file something like this :

```
echo "Aldi:01|Andi:02|Martin:03";
```

So my question is, how to `.split()` that outputted string(`tags`) become **JS array** with format like :

```
var source: [
                {'value' : 'Aldi', 'id' : '01'},
                {'value' : 'Andi', 'id' : '02'},
                {'value' : 'Martin', 'id' : '03'}
            ]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly does `call_ajax` do? Does it return the response synchronously, or the request promise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the [Array `map` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
var source = tags.split("|") // first split by `|`
  .map(function(tag) {
    // then construct the object for each part
    var parts = tag.split(":");
    return { value: parts[0], id: parts[1] };
  });
```

Comment: Quick Note: IE8 doesn't have `.map()`. Could use jQuery's `.map()` instead.

Comment: @BillCriswell: … or better just [shim it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Compatibility)

Comment: Yeah. Only said that cause it's tagged with jquery.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with two splits pretty easily.

```
var s = 'Aldi:01|Andi:02|Martin:03', 
    parts = s.split('|'), 
    source = [];

for( var i = 0, l = parts.length; i < l; i++ ){
  var part = parts[i].split(':');
  source.push({ value: part[0], id: part[1] });
}
```

Comment: I don't know where is the mistake, but it's doesn't work Bill

Comment: I copy and pasted right into the console and `sources` returned what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

```
var output = 'Aldi:01|Andi:02|Martin:03';
var data = output.split('|');
var source = new Array();

for(var key in data){
    var temp = data[key].split(':');
    source[key] = {'value':temp[0],'id':temp[1]};
}
```

By using,

```
for(var key in source){
    alert(source[key]['value']);
    alert(source[key]['id']);
}
```

Comment: Yeah. Actually I use that array for jQuery.autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

First split the string by the bar character `.split('|')` to get an array of three items, then loop through each of those items and split them again for the value/id pairs and put it into your final array.

```
var responseEcho; // assume this is your response from the server.
var myArray = responseEcho.split('|');
var finalArray = [];
myArray.forEach(function(data) {
  var dataArray = data.split(':');
  finalArray.push({'value': dataArray[0], 'id': dataArray[1]});
});
```

You may want to include a bit more safety checking just in case, but that is the general idea.

Comment: Are you mixing PHP with JavaScript syntax here?

Comment: Everything is good besides the `finalArray[]`. It would need to be `finalArray.push({value: dataArray[0], id: dataArray[1]});` Also the array setup. It would need `finalArray = []`

Comment: Great idea. But why `myArray.forEach(function(data)` doesn't work? I had tried

Comment: It's a newer standard. THe solution I added is pretty safe a ways back browser support wise.

Comment: @AldiUnanto sorry, I wrote it too fast and didn't check my work very well, I forgot to add the closing `);` to the end of the forEach function call.